# How to design reaction and menu UI for chat app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to design the reaction and menu ui as like below Image in Flutter.

[image]

Please suggest me best way to implement this.

I have tried to search packages from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) but didn't got anything matches this ui.

Also I have tried **CupertinoContextMenu** But its showing all messages in center of the screen when I trigger the Context Menu.

Comment: i don't know if there are any ready to use package are available but you try implementing overlay.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-implementing-overlay/

Comment: I think I need to customize as per requirements.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I implemented with this code

```
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100
                  )
                )
              ]
            )
          )
        )
      );
    }
  );
```

Comment: Here It will show dialog always in centre in screen. do you have solution for that?

Comment: you can do that by alignment

Comment: That is not working my side. Could you provide code snippets?

Comment: When I change the alignment to topLeft, the position changes here the code you most changed 
alignment: Alignment.topLeft